# Euler's explicit method on MATLAB raises error with example

Tags: matlab, math, numerical-methods, differential-equations

This is my code for Euler's explicit Method on MATLAB

```
function [t,x] = meuler(f, intervalo, x0, N)
h = (intervalo(2)-intervalo(1))/N;
t = intervalo(1):h:intervalo(2);
x(:,1) = x0(:);
for i = 1:N
    x(i+1,:) = x(i,:) + h*(f(t(i),x(i,:)));
end
```

It takes a function `f` defined in another file. When I try to run the code with the following function

```
function f = funccorazon(t,x)
f1 = x(2);
f2 = 16*x(1)+4*sin(2*t);
f=[f1;f2];
```

I get this error

```
>> meuler(@funccorazon, [0 2*pi], [0 2], 1000)
Attempted to access y(2); index out of bounds because numel(y)=1.

Error in funccorazon (line 2)
f1 = y(2);
```

and I don't know why. Apparently, when I solve the differential equation using `ode45`, nothing seems to go wrong. Any help with that would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is that you need to work with row vectors instead of column vectors.

first, in your function call, define the input x0 as row vector:

```
meuler(@funccorazon, [0 2*pi], [0,2], 1000)
```

second, in funccorazon function, define the output f similarly:

```
f=[f1,f2];
```

lastly, in meuler function do the following changes:

```
x = zeros(N,2);
x(1,:) = x0;
```

Comment: Thank you! It works now. Just one thing, is there a reason why I should work with row vectors instead? Not that I'm fond of column vectors, but just wondering why.

Comment: no specific reason to prefer rows over columns. The important thing is to choose one of them and remain consistent along the program

Comment: The most important error should be the last one, as that mix-up of counting index and vector component index is directly responsible for the observed error.